# The correct understanding of limits

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

*I want to be sure that I'm understanding the concept of limits correctly*.

When I faced the concept of limits for the first time I've been told that the definition of a limit is:

> $\lim _{x\to \:a}$ $f(x)$ $=$ $L$

Is that when the values of $x$ get closer to the value $a$, the values of $f(x)$ get closer to the value $L$?

But I see this definition is a vague and wrong one. Besides if we consider the constant function $f(x) = c$ the definition doesn't hold: ''if $x$ gets closer to $a$ the values of $f(x)$ stay the same and don't get closer to any value".

Then I read Tom Apostol's Calculus and the definition the book provides is the statement $\lim _{x\to \:a}$ $f(x)$ $=$ $L$  means that we can make the values of $f(x)$ as close as we please to the number ($L$), provided that we make the values of $x$ sufficiently close to $a$.

This definition provides no ambiguities and makes perfect sense with every function.

*My question: Is the first definition I wrote really a wrong one because I see any one that introduces limits begin with definition and am I really understanding what Tom Apostol really wants to say?*

Note: What I wrote about the definition that Tom Apostol provides is how I understand it and I know that the the rigor definition is the $\epsilon -\delta$ but I see that the $\epsilon -\delta$ definition is just a rigor translation of what I've said about the definition that Tom Apostol provides.

Correct me if I've written anything wrong.

Comment: The first Definition you state can be confusing because it is not clear what "getting closer" means formally. For instance, if you take $f(x)=x^2$, then, as $x\to 0$, we have that $f(x)$ gets closer to $-1$, but $\lim_{x\to 0} x^2\neq -1$.

Comment: Looks good to me. Your initial "definition" is useful for intuition, but it isn't really a definition because it involves phrases that aren't defined.

Comment: @SammyBlack indeed but the initial ''definition'' is also ambiguous in many examples one of them I've stated in my question which is the constant function $f(x)$$=$$c$ 
and there is another example which is $f(x)$$=$$xsin(1/x)$ if $x$ gets closer to $0$ the function gets closer to $0$ and then go away from $0$ so there is no ''getting closer'' in that way

Comment: Just observing that c is extremely close to c.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Nice counterexample.

Comment: @law-of-fives 
*well* this indeed hold but in the $\epsilon$ $-$ $\delta$ because $\left|c-c\right|=0<\epsilon$  and this holds because what matters is after all our definition and if we consider the $\epsilon - \delta$ one  it holds perfectly but as I've said the first definition I've wrote states as $x$ gets closer to $a$ the $f(x)$ must gets closer to some value $L$ and this doesn't hold in constant case it just stays the same for all the function besides the statement in Math is not understood until well defined and this one is not well defined and an ambiguous one so It's WRONG

Comment: It occurs to me that even the Apostol formulation is lacking in completeness, and should probably say something like "... we can make the values of $f(x)$ remain as close as we please to the number ($L$) ..." (I've added the word "remain").

Comment: $\lim _{x\to a}  f(x) = L$ is not a definition, it is just a *notation* meaning what you wrote in the next sentence. This is in fact a bit vague, but it is not wrong. You say that the  constant function $f(x)=c$ does not have this property: If $x$ gets closer to $a$, the values of $f(x)$ stay the same and don't get closer to any value. It seems that you understand "getting closer to $L$" as $f(x) \ne L$ if $x \ne a$, but this is not the case. If $f(x) = L$, then it is close to $L$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Why does $x^2$ gets closer to $-1$ as $x \to 0$?

Comment: @KritikerderElche It gets closer to $-1$ the same way it gets closer to $-100$.

Comment: @PaulFrost 
if we try to formalize the ''getting closer or approaching '' definition will have a condition like that:
if $t$ is closer to $a$ than $y$ then $f(t)$ will be closer to $L$ than $f(y)$
and if we try to write this words in rigor statement will be something like this:
if $\left|t-a\right|<\left|y-a\right|$ then this provides that $\left|f\left(t\right)-L\right|<\left|f\left(y\right)-L\right|$ 
and this condition isn't fulfilled in $f(x)=c$

Comment: @shehab If this is your understanding of getting closer, then this is possible only for certain functions which are injective in a neighborhood of $a$. But this not the only interpretation. I understand it in the sense of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition. But vague things of course give rise to different interpretations.

Comment: @PaulFrost 
you're correct the vague things give rise to different interpretations and this why of course we need a definition , you're free to choose the interpretation that fit well for your intuition as long as you understand the  $ϵ-δ$ definition but I'm still against the ''getting closer'' definition for what I've written

Answer (score 2):

This touches a bit on the pedagogy of math: the first definition isn't so much *wrong* as it is propaedeutic. It is meant to give you a first feeling for the subject, rather than hitting you with something that covers all the edge cases. But yes, the case of a constant function you mentioned isn't covered by the first definition which, if formalized, would probably look like this:

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ if the following holds: when $x$ is sufficiently close to $a$, then $f(x)$ can be made as close to $L$ as we please, and if $x$ is closer to $a$ than $y$ is, then $f(x)$ is closer to $L$ than $f(y)$ is.

The latter sentence reflects the "getting closer" aspect of the first definition, and it's clearly wrong. Not just in your edge case of a constant function, but also for a sine function, because the function is not monotonic on either side of the limit point, as this definition would imply.

Apostols wordy definition is better, but still slightly ambiguous, imho. What does it mean that we *can* make $f(x)$ close to $L$? For instance, consider the Dirichlet function $D$, which is $1$ for rational and $0$ for irrational arguments. Is $\lim_{x\to0}D(x)=1$? Taken very literally, according to Apostols wordy definition it's true, because in every small neighborhood of $0$ there are always points such that $D(x)=1$, so we *can* make $D(x)$ as close to $1$ as we want by choosing a "good" $x$ which is sufficiently close to $0$. But the formal definition disagrees: the limit of the Dirichlet function does not exist at any point, because it oscillates way too wildly.

So here's an in-between step towards the formal definition:

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ if the following holds: If we pick a positive distance as small as we want, and if we choose $x$ sufficiently close to (but not coinciding with) $a$, then $f(x)$ will be closer to $L$ than the previously chosen distance.

This way, it's clearer that if $x$ is sufficiently close to $a$, then $f(x)$ *must* be close enough to $L$, instead of there only existing an $x$ in that "sufficiently close region" for which $f(x)$ is close enough to $L$.

The formal definition just makes a logical formula out of this: distances are the absolute values of the differences, the chosen distance is $\varepsilon$, "sufficiently close" means that there exists a $\delta$ such that ... And so on.

Comment: firstly: you've provided in the first of your answer an elegant way to prove that the ''getting closer or approaching'' definition is wrong,
Secondly:Apostol's definition meant to convey an idea which is : $f(x)$ can be made as close to $L$ as we like provided that $x$ sufficiently close to $a$ 
the phrases like ''can be made as close to as we like or sufficiently close '' are meant to say: if we can make our function values within any neighborhood around $L$ let say $N(L)$  and we've found for any neighborhood around $L$ a sufficient neighborhood around $a$ then we can say $limx→a f(x) = L$

Comment: Lol, when you have to explain how basic math education is not 'wrong' :D

Comment: I think the example you use to critique Apostol's prose is a stretch. The wording is correct if you read "make" as "guarantee" rather than "sometimes make".

Answer (score 0):

> Is that when the values of $x$ get closer to the value $a$, the values of $f(x)$ get closer to the value $L$?
> But I see this definition is a vague and wrong one.

Well, that's because it's not a definition but rather a paraphrase, and it is a vague one.  What it is **not supposed to mean** is that when $x$-values get closer to $a$, then $y$-values get closer to $L$, i.e.
$$
|x_2-a| < |x_1-a| \qquad \not\!\!\!\!\implies \quad |f(x_2)-L| < |f(x_1)-L|
$$

What one does instead, is to limit the possible deviation from $L$, i.e. one wants that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ for all $x$ that are close enough to $a$.  The point is then that $\varepsilon$ might be arbitrarily small, i.e. *for all* values of $\varepsilon>0$ it must be possible to find some $\delta > 0$, such that for all $x$ close enough to $a$, the value of $|f(x)-L|$ must not exceed $\varepsilon$:
$$
|x-a| < \delta \quad\implies\quad |f(x)-L| < \varepsilon
$$

This means that

> the values of $f(x)$ get closer to the value $L$

in the sense that the maximal allowed deviation from $L$ can be made arbitrarily small.  This includes the case where $f(x)=L$ for all $x$, because $|f(x)-L|=0<\varepsilon$ is satisfied trivially.

> Taken very literally, according to Apostols wordy definition

So the bottom line is:  Beware of wordy definitions! And in the math books you mention, the paraphrased definitions are presumably not in a proper definition, i.e. not in a section labeled **Definition:**.  One could use words only, but that would get too lengthy and convoluted.

Comment: You are correct but in your last paragraph you've said:''So the bottom line is: Beware of wordy definitions! And in the math books you mention, the paraphrased definitions are presumably not in a proper definition....". ,,But there something I want to clarify before developing any definition we should've Mathematical intuition about it and this intuition isn't wrong but we develop it more and more to remove it from any ambiguities to produce a mathematical definition  so this wordy definition is important to understand the Mathematical intuition of the definition